# CSS : Failed to load resource in chrome

Tags: css, django, google-chrome

I have a django site running locally. Everything seems ok except the CSS files that can not be loaded by Chrome. I can see a `Failed to load resource` error in the console.

- The site is ok in firefox
- The site is ok if I get the css not from the local server but from the production server
- The css source can be viewed correctly
- I have no special blocker plugin install
- The css is rather big but I still have the issue if I use a very short file
- I have similar issues with some js files (ckeditor)
- It works of with some other css and js (admin css for example)
- The django app has been developped with 1.0 and I am in the process of moving it to 1.4. The css and js files are served as media

Any idea?

Comment: if ctrl-f5 doesn't work (you may need to hit it a couple of times) then open the network tab in developer tools (f12) and reload

Comment: same results with ctrl+f5. in network tab, i can see that the file has been downloaded properly (code 200) and that the content type is ok (text/css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the real cause but the problem is solved. Maybe because it was served as media and now it is served as a static.

Comment: can you explain this further please? The answer isn't very helpful. Where did you make the changes?

Comment: I don't know exactly what fixed the problem. I've migrated the project to django 1.4. I think no-one noticed the problem before. It was served as media by django dev server. When I start serving this file as a static, the problem disappeared. I think there is a little difference between django serves this different type of file. But, unfortunately, I don't the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: My problem turned out to be because of the Adblock extension. Thanks anyway.